# xcrun invalid active developer path error in macOS

Tags: ios, r, xcode, error-handling

I have recently updated my Mac to Catalina, but have been knitting Rmd documents just fine up to this point.

In a current document, I am getting the following error when I try to knit:

**xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun**

I don't know why this particular markdown document is creating an issue when the others weren't. I have looked elsewhere on Stack, where I tried the following:

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select --reset
```

Both of these lines of code just gave me an *object not found* error.

I ran these with no luck:

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

I then realized these commands should go in the terminal, but still have no luck.

I went to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and downloaded Command line tools OS Xcode 12.3dmg package.

I then tried all of the above code in the *terminal*, including:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Now, instead of giving me the error message that I started with, the knit just loads indefinitely.

At this point, I'm just throwing crap at the wall, without knowing what it is that I'm actually doing. Any guidance from this point is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Commands like `xcode-select --install` should be run in the terminal. That's not an R command. It's not exactly clear what you mean why you say "knit just loads indefinitely". What exactly are you seeing? Can you open and verify that XCode has been installed before running R?

Comment: @MrFlick yeah, I realized those commands should go in the terminal. When I run `xcode-select --install` in the terminal, it says _command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates_ but I don't know what to actually do from there.  The markdown files just never knits. It stays at 44% with the loading icon and stop sign never going away.

Comment: As an update, it says this in my terminal: `The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run chsh -s /bin/zsh`.  When I run that in the terminal, it asks for a password, of which I do not know, it it won't even let me type anything anyway. I can only press enter.

Comment: Second Update - FIXED: I took out the line of R code I had `view(DataName)` and now it knits just fine. Don't know why that was an issue, but I guess I won't use that again.

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue was `view()` instead of `View()`.